# How to make a function accept and output a Dataframe series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sort a Dataframe along one column, using a callable. Pandas docs says the callable needs to expect a series and return a series with the same shape. I am using this below function, adapted from two others, that takes a list of Hex colors and sorts in a specific way.

```
result = pd.DataFrame(frame)

def step (hexrgb, repetitions=1):
    r, g, b = (int(hexrgb[i:i+2], 16) / 255.0 for i in range(0,5,2))
    colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b)
    lum = math.sqrt( .241 * r + .691 * g + .068 * b )
    h, s, v = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r,g,b)
    h2 = int(h * repetitions)
    lum2 = int(lum * repetitions)
    v2 = int(v * repetitions)
    return (colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h2, lum, v2))


print(result.sort_values(by=['First Color'], key=step))
```

There may be any number of errors here but the main thing, it seems, is getting the function to accept and output a series:

```
0    c89664
1    e1c8af
2    c8c896
3    c8c8af
4    e1af96
```

Any help appreciated as I am new to this.

Comment: if `a = [1, 2, 3]`, then you can always do `return pd.Series(a)` and it will return a series. If you are sending a series, you can always return a series. Are you asking if `def step` function can accept and return a `pd.Series`?

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly, `result['First Color']` contains 'hexrgb' values, so try:

```py
result.sort_values(by='First Color', key=lambda col: step(col))
```